# interpretar conta em string C#

Tags: c#

olá, precisava resolver uma string com uma conta (ex. 2 + 2) no C# e retornar um integer (ex. 4)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string str = "2 + 2";
    int resultado = Calcular(str);
    Console.WriteLine("Resultado => {0}",resultado);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

alguma dica?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A biblioteca [NCalc](https://github.com/sheetsync/NCalc) simplifica isso para você. Instale ela pelo Nuget:

```
Install-Package ncalc
```

Depois utilize dessa forma:

```
using NCalc;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string str = "2 + 2";
            var expressao = new Expression(str);
            Console.WriteLine("Resultado => {0}", expressao.Evaluate());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, testei aqui e funcionou, só mais uma coisa, se eu tiver algo como "resolva a média destes valores: 2,4", existe algum jeito de eu fazer a média, ou pelo menos remover o texto e deixar apenas os valores com a vírgula?

Comment: @JacksonJoséGomesDoValle um método genérico que faça isso seria complicado, precisa ter uma regra para saber como extrair os números do texto. Uma forma seria tirar tudo que não seja número e vírgula, mas daí se a pessoa digitasse vírgula na frase dela, já não funcionaria. Aí talvez você tivesse que achar a primeira ocorrência de algum número (ex: 2) e pegar tudo o que tiver dali até a última ocorrência de algum número (no caso pegaria 2,4). Daí você faz `var nums = textoExtraido.Split(',');` e depois algo como `var media = nums.Select(n => Convert.ToInt32(n)).Average();`.

Comment: ok, vou tentar valeu pela resposta

Comment: Você pode testar o pacote https://www.nuget.org/packages/RMdev.Calculator, ele é mais simples que o ncalc, por enquanto trabalha apenas com números, mas ele tem a função Avg(a,b,c, ...), os dois pacotes permitem você pode criar suas próprias funcões.

Answer (score 1):

Eu utilizo a seguinte função:

```
        /// <summary>
    /// Calcular Formulas
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="evaluationString"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string CalculateFormula(string evaluationString)
    {
        Microsoft.JScript.Vsa.VsaEngine en = Microsoft.JScript.Vsa.VsaEngine.CreateEngine();
        Object result = Microsoft.JScript.Eval.JScriptEvaluate(evaluationString, en);

        return result.ToString();
    }
```